# O que são propriedades lógicas no CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Recentemente encontrei o conceito de  "propriedades lógicas no CSS". Ao que me parece, é um novo sistema de se criar o CSS de forma lógica, e não física (direção e posições fixas, digamos assim).

No entanto, essa definição e conceito ainda me parecem confusos, então:

- O que são as propriedades lógicas no CSS?
- Qual problema elas vieram para resolver?

Comment: Cara realmente é difícil de entender, e mais difícil ainda de explicar rss

Comment: Vou deixar para outra pessoa responder! 

Comment: Preciso acrescentar mais algo a minha resposta?

Comment: Francamente, não sei. Vou esperar mais respostas para ter uma base de comparação...

Comment: Por que o negativo?

Comment: Seria isso [CSS Logical Properties](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/css-logical-properties)?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, sim! Creio que sim. :-)

Answer (score 7):

> As propriedades lógicas do CSS definem uma nova maneira de trabalhar com o layout. Seu principal objetivo é ajudar os desenvolvedores a suportar diferentes sistemas de escrita, como *scripts* da direita-para-esquerda (RTL) e exibidos na vertical. Esses novos recursos tornam possível controlar o layout por meio de propriedades lógicas, e não físicas, por exemplo com propriedades lógicas você pode descrever o `start` (início) e `end` (fim) de um elemento ao invés de seus limites no `left` (esquerda) e `right` (direita). Consegue ver a diferença?

[Fonte](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-css-logical-properties--cms-33024)

Caso você queira definir uma margem `margin-left: 100px` em um elemento que deve se adaptar a direção e ao sistema de escrita do seu conteúdo, você pode usar a propriedade lógica `margin-inline-start: 100px` que vai ser inteligente o suficiente para isso. Ou seja você usa a lógica de usar uma margem no início de uma linha e não definir uma margem à esquerda! Dessa forma mesmo que o sistema de escrita seja vertical-esquerda-para-direita, baixo-para-cima, direita-para-esquerda, a margem do elemento irá se adaptar ao sistema de escrita!

[image: Gif com um exemplo visual]

Percebe como o elemento se adapta baseado no sistema de escrita utilizando a lógica? Isso não seria possível utilizando apenas CSS caso fosse usado as propriedades físicas!

[Outras](https://css-tricks.com/css-logical-properties/) [fontes](https://adrianroselli.com/2019/11/css-logical-properties.html) [que](https://blogs.igalia.com/mrego/2018/08/08/css-logical-properties-and-values-in-chromium/) [podem](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/03/understanding-logical-properties-values/) ser úteis (note que são 4 *links* diferentes)

[Uma lista com algumas propriedades lógicas e seus valores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties)

Comment: Gostaria de ver algum exemplo prático, para entender melhor a teoria...