# Como funciona a propriedade inline-size?

Tags: css, css3

Eu estava dando uma fuçada no console do navegador ajustando um elemento, e percebi que o Google Chrome completou uma propriedade chamada `inline-size`. Não me lembro de ter visto essa propriedade antes, mas percebi que ela afeta o tamanho dos elementos que usam a mesma.

Pesquisei sobre ela, mas vi pouca explicação sobre a mesma.

Me surgiu algumas dúvidas:

- Essa propriedade é nova?
- Como ela funciona? Que problema ela resolve?
- Quais são navegadores têm suporte?
- Ela tem alguma relação com elementos que possuam o atributo `display` com os valores prefixados por `inline-`?

Comment: Ela funciona de forma lógica 

Comment: Relacionado: [O que são propriedades lógicas no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/427573/69296)

Answer (score -2):

A propriedade do CSS inline-size define o tamanho horizontal e vertical de um elemento bloco. Ele é correspondente a cada propriedade width ou a height, dependendo do valor de writing-mode.

Espero ter ajudado.